# Cannot run two Tensorflow sessions using Keras and a GPU server

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I can't run two Keras python program at the same time on my GPU server. I have a GPU server with 8 GPUs. What I want is to run another python program (either on the same GPU or on another one). I have tried running the code using this line but it didn't work: 
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES

I also tried to run the code on another GPU but I don't know how to do that with Keras. It worked fine on Tensorflow.

```
with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
```

Here are the details of the error:

Error screenshot:

[image: click to see the errors]

Comment: Thanks Curious for the edit!